# JavaScript get focus on element/tag and move around with cursor key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-events

I have created an calendar application, a full page calendar, but the problem is I want that whenever the calendar page loads today date focused/selected automatically, and I can use arrow keys to move around dates.
For example if I use left arrow key the previous date get focused/selected and etc.

Please give me any possible solution in JavaScript or jQuery. I used divs to separate each item of calendar.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) You could at least show a sample of your existing html structure.

Comment: i just tried simple javascript to generate calendar, i know the focus is used to focus on input fields, i also like to know is it possible to focus on some tags like div or table tags?

Comment: You can't really focus on div or table elements. The best way to do it is to use anchor (`<a>`) elements - this allows both mouse and keyboard users to use your page. Your question implies you've already generated the calendar without this arrow key feature, so again: show your existing code (or at least the generated html).

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to each div. For example

```
<div class="calendar" id="day1"></div>
<div class="calendar" id="day2"></div>
```

and some javascript

```
var date = new date();  //GET DATE INFORMATION
var day = date.getDate(); //EXTRACT DAY OF MONTH

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#day'+day).css("outline-style","solid"); //ADD FOCUS TO CURRENT DAY

  $('body').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keycode == 37){  //IF LEFT ARROW
      $(".calendar").css("outline-style","none");
      day = day - 1;  
      $('#day'+day).css("outline-style","solid");
    }
    if (e.keycode == 39){  //IF RIGHT ARROW
      $(".calendar").css("outline-style","none");
      day = day + 1;
      $('#day'+day).css("outline-style","solid");
    }
  });

});
```

and some css

```
.calendar{
outline-style:none;
outline-width:1px;
outline-color:<YOUR CHOICE>;
}
```

This solution does not account for clicking left arrow when it is the first of the month or right arrow when it is the last of the month, but the idea is there.